# How to wrap text in tcbtheorem

Tags: theorems, tcolorbox, wrap

I think my problem might be really basic, but I went through the documentation and could not figure out how to force text to wrap inside a tcolorbox title, when the title is too long.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\tcbset{
    thmbox/.style={
        enhanced,
        breakable,
        sharp corners=all,
        fonttitle=\bfseries\normalsize,
        fontupper=\normalsize\itshape,
        top=0mm,
        bottom=0mm,
        right=0mm,
        colback=white,
        colframe=white,
        colbacktitle=white,
        coltitle=black,
        attach boxed title to top left,
        boxed title style={empty, size=minimal, bottom=1.5mm},
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-%
                  (frame.south east)--(frame.north east);},
        overlay first={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--  ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);
            \draw (frame.north east)--(frame.south east);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);
            \draw (frame.north east)--(frame.south east);},
        overlay last={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-%
                  (frame.south east)--(frame.north east);},
    },
}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{questionbox}{Question}{thmbox}{qst}

\begin{document}

\begin{questionbox}{\lipsum[66]}{qst:1}
\lipsum[1]
\end{questionbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: At the moment your example does not even compile

Comment: Try `\newrobustcmd{\mytitle}{\parbox[t]{0.7\textwidth}{\lipsum[1]}}` to make a robust title box and use `\mytitle` instead of `\lipsum[66]` as title. The title in a theorem is just a `\hbox` which does neither wrap etc, unless using an inner parbox. It will not break like the real `tcolorbox` content. Just reduce your title -- that's the best option.

Comment: That's strange. I just copied the text into a new document and it compiled.

Where in my code do I add `\newrobustcmd{\mytitle}{\parbox[t]{0.7\textwidth}{\lipsum[1]‌​}}`

Wouldn't that print the same title every time? i.e. the contents of `\lipsum[1]`? I am still trying to figure out how things work. 

What I want to do, though, is to enter questions of variable size in the title (possibly up to 3 or 4 lines) and the answer in the body of the theorem box. I guess I'm trying to merge the theorem and the proof environments in the two boxes of `tcolorbox`, if that makes any sense

Comment: @Mahoma You can use one box for both questions and answers. Questions are included in upper part and answers in lower. `tcolorbox` documentation shows several examples like these. Two special examples are shown in my answers to [how-to-defer-content-to-a-later-part-of-the-document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224429/1952) and [hide-content-to-show-later](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257455/1952) where solutions are shown later on in your document.

Comment: @Mahoma: Of course you must change the `\mytitle` box each time. But the two - box approach is the better one.

Answer (score 2):

As Christian explained, tcolorbox title is not wrapped. It's supposed to be some word and not a complete exercise. But if you want to mix questions and answers into the same color box, based on you format a possible solution could be to use a short title (or an empty one) and place the question in upper tcolorbox part while solution in placed in the lower part. Something like

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\tcbset{
    thmbox/.style={
        enhanced,
        breakable,
        sharp corners=all,
        fonttitle=\bfseries\normalsize,
        fontupper=\normalsize,
        fontlower=\normalsize\itshape,
        before lower={\itshape Solution:\ },
        top=0mm,
        bottom=0mm,
        right=0mm,
        colback=white,
        colframe=white,
        colbacktitle=white,
        coltitle=black,
        attach boxed title to top left,
        boxed title style={empty, size=minimal, bottom=1.5mm},
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-%
                  (frame.south east)--(frame.north east);},
        overlay first={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--  ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);
            \draw (frame.north east)--(frame.south east);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);
            \draw (frame.north east)--(frame.south east);},
        overlay last={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-%
                  (frame.south east)--(frame.north east);},
    },
}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{questionbox}{Question}{thmbox}{qst}

\begin{document}

\begin{questionbox}{A nice question}{qst:1}
\lipsum[1]
\tcblower
\lipsum[2]
\end{questionbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I really like the solutions in your links!
The only problem now is that when I print the list off `tcbtheorems` I no longer get the questions to be listed. I've been trying to figure out how to collect the contents of the `tcolorbox` rather than the title, since the question is no longer a title.
I tried using this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184764/collect-contents-of-lists-at-beginning-of-document but I am not really understanding the options to adapt them to the colorbox